# Kustomize overlays when using a shared ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kubectl, configmap, kustomize

I have an environment made of pods that address their target environment based on an environment variable called `CONF_ENV` that could be `test`, `stage` or `prod`.

The application running inside the Pod has the same source code across environments, the configuration file is picked according to the `CONF_ENV` environment variable.

I'v encapsulated this `CONF_ENV` in `*.properties` files just because I may have to add more environment variables later, but I make sure that each property file contains the expected `CONF_ENV` e.g.:

- `test.properites` has `CONF_ENV=test`,
- `prod.properties` has `CONF_ENV=prod`, and so on...

I struggle to make this work with Kustomize overlays, because I want to define a `ConfigMap` as a shared resource across all the pods within the same overlay e.g. `test` (each pod in their own directory, along other stuff when needed).

So the idea is:

- `base/` (shared) with the definition of the `Namespace`, the `ConfigMap` (and potentially other shared resources
- `base/pod1/` with the definition of pod1 picking from the shared `ConfigMap` (this defaults to `test`, but in principle it could be different)

Then the overlays:

- `overlay/test` that patches the base with `CONF_ENV=test` (e.g. for `overlay/test/pod1/` and so on)
- `overlay/prod/` that patches the base with `CONF_ENV=prod` (e.g. for `overlay/prod/pod1/` and so on)

Each directory with their own `kustomize.yaml`.

The above doesn't work because when going into e.g. `overlay/test/pod1/` and I invoke the command `kubectl kustomize .` to check the output YAML, then I get all sorts of errors depending on how I defined the lists for the YAML keys `bases:` or `resources:`.

I am trying to share the `ConfigMap` across the entire `CONF_ENV` environment in an attempt to **minimize the boilerplate YAML** by leveraging the patching-pattern with Kustomize.

The Kubernetes / Kustomize YAML directory structure works like this:

```sh
├── base
│   ├── configuration.yaml # I am trying to share this!
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── my_namespace.yaml # I am trying to share this!
│   ├── my-scheduleset-etl-misc
│   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   └── my_scheduleset_etl_misc.yaml
│   ├── my-scheduleset-etl-reporting
│   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   └── my_scheduleset_etl_reporting.yaml
│   └── test.properties # I am trying to share this!
└── overlay
    └── test
        ├── kustomization.yaml # here I want tell "go and pick up the shared resources in the base dir"
        ├── my-scheduleset-etl-misc
        │   ├── kustomization.yaml
        │   └── test.properties # I've tried to share this one level above, but also to add this inside the "leaf" level for a given pod
        └── my-scheduleset-etl-reporting
            └── kustomization.yaml
```

The command `kubectl` with Kustomize:

- sometimes complains that the shared namespace does not exist:

```
error: merging from generator &{0xc001d99530 {  map[] map[]} {{ my-schedule-set-props merge {[CONF_ENV=test] [] [] } <nil>}}}: 
id resid.ResId{Gvk:resid.Gvk{Group:"", Version:"v1", Kind:"ConfigMap", isClusterScoped:false}, Name:"my-schedule-set-props", Namespace:""} 
does not exist; cannot merge or replace
```

- sometimes doesn't allow to have shared resources inside an overlay:

```
error: loading KV pairs: env source files: [../test.properties]: 
security; file '/my/path/to/yaml/overlay/test/test.properties' 
is not in or below '/my/path/to/yaml/overlay/test/my-scheduleset-etl-misc'
```

- sometimes doesn't allow cycles when I am trying to have multiple bases - the shared resources and the original pod definition:

```
error: accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources from '../': 
'/my/path/to/yaml/overlay/test' must resolve to a file': 
cycle detected: candidate root '/my/path/to/yaml/overlay/test' 
contains visited root '/my/path/to/yaml/overlay/test/my-scheduleset-etl-misc'
```

The overlay `kustomization.yaml` files inside the pod dirs have:

```yaml
bases:
  - ../ # tried with/without this to share the ConfigMap
  - ../../../base/my-scheduleset-etl-misc/
```

The `kustomization.yaml` at the root of the overlay has:

```yaml
bases:
  - ../../base
```

The `kustomization.yaml` at the base dir contains this configuration for the ConfigMap:

```yaml
# https://gist.github.com/hermanbanken/3d0f232ffd86236c9f1f198c9452aad9
configMapGenerator:
  - name: my-schedule-set-props
    namespace: my-ss-schedules
    envs:
      - test.properties

vars:
  - name: CONF_ENV
    objref:
      kind: ConfigMap
      name: my-schedule-set-props
      apiVersion: v1
    fieldref:
      fieldpath: data.CONF_ENV

configurations:
  - configuration.yaml
```

With `configuration.yaml` containing:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

varReference:
- path: spec/confEnv/value
  kind: Pod
```

How do I do this?

How do I make sure that I minimise the amount of YAML by sharing all the `ConfigMap` stuff and the Pods definitions as much as I can?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, I think you may be grossly over-complicating things. I *think* you want a common properties file defined in your base, but you want to override specific properties in your overlays. Here's one way of doing that.

In base, I have:

```
$ cd base
$ tree
.
├── example.properties
├── kustomization.yaml
└── pod1
    ├── kustomization.yaml
    └── pod.yaml
```

Where `example.properties` contains:

```
SOME_OTHER_VAR=somevalue
CONF_ENV=test
```

And `kustomization.yaml` contains:

```
resources:
  - pod1

configMapGenerator:
  - name: example-props
    envs:
      - example.properties
```

I have two overlays defined, `test` and `prod`:

```
$ cd ../overlays
$ tree
.
├── prod
│   ├── example.properties
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── test
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

`test/kustomization.yaml` looks like this:

```
resources:
- ../../base
```

It's just importing the `base` without any changes, since the value of `CONF_ENV` from the `base` directory is `test`.

`prod/kustomization.yaml` looks like this:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base

configMapGenerator:
  - name: example-props
    behavior: merge
    envs:
      - example.properties
```

And `prod/example.properties` looks like:

```
CONF_ENV=prod
```

If I run `kustomize build overlays/test`, I get as output:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  CONF_ENV: test
  SOME_OTHER_VAR: somevalue
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example-props-7245222b9b
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - 1800
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: example-props-7245222b9b
    image: docker.io/alpine
    name: alpine
```

If I run `kustomize build overlays/prod`, I get:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  CONF_ENV: prod
  SOME_OTHER_VAR: somevalue
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example-props-h4b5tc869g
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - 1800
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: example-props-h4b5tc869g
    image: docker.io/alpine
    name: alpine
```

That is, everything looks as you would expect given the configuration in `base`, but we have provided a new value for `CONF_ENV`.

You can find all these files [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-71008589).

Comment: This is great! I've implemented the pattern and it works. However, I need to be able to generate the relevant YAML only for a given `podX`. I usually do this because I am able to target a directory with `kubectl kustomize path/to/overlay/prod/pod1`, but in `prod` there is no directory for e.g. `pod1`, how do I do this? I need to make sure it contains the shared resources as well e.g. the ConfigMap (and a Namespace)