# Is there a way to split a ConfigMap into two without having them overwrite each other?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm, configmap

So I have a JCasC ConfigMap containing

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: master-jcasc
  namespace: master-namespace
data:
  entries.yaml: |
    master:
      JCasC:
        defaultConfig: false
        configScripts:
         jenkins-settings: |
           field1: ...
           field2: ...
           jobs:
             - script: >
                 someJobDefenition
```

And keeping the `jobs` section here in the Jcasc file works when I `k apply`, however when I create another ConfigMap with just the `jobs` in it, they keep overwriting each other.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: jobs-file
  namespace: master-namespace
data:
  entries.yaml: |
    master:
      JCasC:
        defaultConfig: false
        configScripts:
         jenkins-settings: |
           jobs:
             - script: >
                 someJobDefenition
```

How can I seperate a ConfigMap into two? without having them overwrite each other?

Comment: How are you mounting the configmap to the pod? Please add this information to the questions as it will help us understand the issue better.

Comment: @YaronIdan using ConfigMapRef. then I'd apply both my configmap and the file that references my ConfigMap, and when I do ```k get cm``` i can see that it has been configured.

Comment: Kubernetes on its own can't merge the values of individual fields in different ConfigMaps that happen to be YAML values.  You tagged this question with [tag:kubernetes-helm]; is a Helm chart generating these ConfigMaps, and could you combine their content there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) to use a separate config file.

As mentioned  in this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008589/) you can use 2 yaml files and create a config map as below :

```
configMapGenerator: 
- name: my-configmap 
  files:
  - datasource1.yaml 
  - datasource2.yaml
```

Where datasourse1.yaml and datasource2.yaml are files which are derived by splitting a config map into two files.

Here is a [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008589/kustomize-overlays-when-using-a-shared-configmap) with another approach.